# project-specific subject lines in svnnotify

Tags: svn

I'm using svnnotify to do post-commit email notifications for projects in a repository. I can use the -P option to specify a subject line prefix, but I'd like to use different prefixes for the different projects matched by multiple invocations of -x. For example, all projects matched by regexp r1 in a -x field should get a subject prefix "NAME1" and all projects matching r2 should get a subject line "NAME2", and so on.

I'm not using the -C flag to introduce context into the subject line, because it's a little too cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons I tend to make a repo for each project it's a pain to have hooks check the path of files changed in a changeset.  Authentication and authorization are also simpler at the repo level than project (path) level.

If I inherited your situation I'd break up the repo and have simple hooks in each one.

If there where political and/or other issues that blocked that plan, use svnlook in your hook to find the paths changed, and set the subject appropriately.